# exluir saldos con 0

Tags: sql-server, sql

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT c.CUENTA, SUBSTRING( c.NOMBRE,0,23) AS 'NOMBRE', SUBSTRING((c.CALLE + ' ' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),c.NRO)),0,22) AS 'DOMICILIO', c.CIUDAD,c.TELEFONO, c.cuit,

(SELECT isnull(sum([dbo].[obtieneSaldoSegunTipoDebe](tdv.CONCEPTO,mcc.TOTAL))- sum([dbo].[obtieneSaldoSegunTipoHaberInforme](tdv.CONCEPTO,mcc.TOTAL)),0)

FROM mOVCtasCtes mcc LEFT JOIN dbo.TablaDeVentas tdv    ON tdv.TIPO = mcc.TIPO WHERE MCC.CUENTA=c.CUENTA and cast(mcc.periodofecha as date)  <=  cast(@fechahasta as date) ) as 'SALDO'

FROM mOVCtasCtes mcc LEFT JOIN dbo.TablaDeVentas tdv    ON tdv.TIPO = mcc.TIPO

LEFT JOIN dbo.Clientes c    ON C.CUENTA=MCC.CUENTA
where c.nombre is not null
and MCC.TOTAL > 0
GROUP BY  c.CUENTA, c.NOMBRE, c.CALLE, c.NRO, c.CIUDAD, c.TELEFONO, c.cuit
ORDER BY c.NOMBRE

END
```

como ven allí un select dentro de () da como resultado una columna que denomino 'SALDO', lo que quiero saber es como evitar que me aparezcan los que tienen saldo 0.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la clausula `NOT IN` en tu `WHERE` para excluir los valores que tengan el 0

```
where c.nombre is not null and MCC.TOTAL > 0 AND SALDO Not In ('0')
```

Prueba y me comentas como te va

Comment: uhhhhh muchisimas gracias kevin, antes había probado lo mismo pero a saldo lo puse con '' ya que creí que debería ser así. funcionó perfecto

Comment: Eso compararía la columna saldo de alguna de las tablas, no la columna calculada en esta consulta.

Comment: Pues, el SALDO que puse yo es el campo calculado que el genera ahi, no estoy hablando especificamente de uno si no de el conjunto total de SALDO que se calcula, pero si te funciono asi, esta perfecto entonces

Comment: @AgustinCallieri Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si te sirvio

Comment: @kevinRestrepo, ahora te hago una consulta mas, vos sabes que el calculo ese que hago en la consulta me quita los decimales, como hago para que aparezcan correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta tiene muchos problemas, desde el formato, las conversiones en columnas dentro del WHERE, hasta el uso de funciones definidas por el usuario. Sin embargo, no puedo dar muchos consejos de como mejorarlos así que simplemente dejo la solución al problema y la advertencia.

Primero, movería la subconsulta al FROM usando APPLY (en este caso usé CROSS pero podría ser OUTER si es necesario).

Después simplemente agrego la columna al WHERE.

```
SELECT c.CUENTA, 
    SUBSTRING( c.NOMBRE,0,23) AS 'NOMBRE', 
    SUBSTRING((c.CALLE + ' ' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),c.NRO)),0,22) AS 'DOMICILIO', 
    c.CIUDAD,
    c.TELEFONO, 
    c.cuit,
    s.Saldo
FROM mOVCtasCtes mcc 
LEFT JOIN dbo.TablaDeVentas tdv    ON tdv.TIPO = mcc.TIPO
LEFT JOIN dbo.Clientes c    ON C.CUENTA=MCC.CUENTA
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(SUM([dbo].[obtieneSaldoSegunTipoDebe](tdv.CONCEPTO,mcc.TOTAL)) 
                         - SUM([dbo].[obtieneSaldoSegunTipoHaberInforme](tdv.CONCEPTO,mcc.TOTAL)),0) AS Saldo
             FROM mOVCtasCtes mcc 
             LEFT JOIN dbo.TablaDeVentas tdv    ON tdv.TIPO = mcc.TIPO 
             WHERE MCC.CUENTA=c.CUENTA 
             and cast(mcc.periodofecha as date)  <=  cast(@fechahasta as date) ) s
where c.nombre is not null
and MCC.TOTAL > 0
AND s.Saldo <> 0
GROUP BY  c.CUENTA, c.NOMBRE, c.CALLE, c.NRO, c.CIUDAD, c.TELEFONO, c.cuit
ORDER BY c.NOMBRE
GO
```

Comment: hola luis entiendo tu comentario pero estoy modificando un pr, ya realizado.
lo que necesito ahora es que me muestre los decimales, cuando hace el sum, para mi, se los esta quitando!